# Add Python prerequiesties to the setup of windows form C# application

Tags: c#, python, winforms, windows-installer, python.net

I wanted to create a setup for my Windows form application. But the application depends on Python 3.6 and python custom library which is made by a third party.
For the integration between C# and Python, I used Pythonnet. Pythonnet was installed using Python 3.6.

So how do I export pythonnet with Python 3.6 in my windows form application setup and install python 3.6 on custom directory location?

OR

Compress the Python3.6 installation folder with site packages and extract it using the setup on custom directory location(eg. C:/).

Answer (score 0):

See this issue for options to package pythonnet apps:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/325

But pyinstaller and cx_freeze may still have limited support for Python 3.6, since it is very recent Python release.